# Connecting to a WCF Service in PHP that has a a NetTCP Binding and a BasicHttpBinding

Tags: .net, php, wcf, nettcpbinding

I have a WCF service. It has multiple clients and three endpoints. The endpoint bindings are nettcp, wsHttp and basicHttp. If I attempt to connect to it via php'd builtin SoapClient class like so:

```
$service = new SoapClient
("http://service.companyname.local:6666/Service/?wsdl",
 array(
         "location" => "http://service.companyname.local:6666/Service/Basic",

    "trace" => true,
    'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1
     )
);
```

I get the following:

```
PHP Fatal error:  SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: PHP-SOAP doesn't support transport 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/soap/tcp' in c:\www\client.php on line 666
```

Right now my workaround is to save the wsdl manually and remove the nettcp binding. Is there a workaround that will allow me to use the automatically generated wsdl? Can I hide a binding from the wsdl in web.config? Can I generate different wsdls on different bindings. I don't want to deploy two service hosts.

Comment: Love that the error shows up on line 666. what does that say? :-)

Comment: Walden, I "sanitized" the error message to protect the guilty file name and line number. Determining what conscious or subconscious feelings I have towards .NET, PHP or the particular task at hand is an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[I filed a feature request with PHP](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=50698). If they implement this I'll mark this as the correct answer. I'm still open to better workarounds though.

**UPDATE:** I submitted a patch to implement this. I am awaiting its approval.
**UPDATE:** Patch committed to svn. Awaiting the next release of PHP.
**UPDATE:** Patch is now part of PHP 5.3.3 and 5.2.14.

Answer (score 1):

When you say you don't want to deploy two service hosts, I assume you're self-hosting a single ServiceHost in a Windows Service. I solved this problem by building a generic service host that can host as many service impls internally as I want (eg, it new's a ServiceHost for each service entry in the config). That way, I can flexibly host as many service impls in a single Windows Service as I need. This would solve your problem by allowing you to separate the basicHttp bound service from the others to keep the WSDL clean. There are some open-source examples of this floating around ([here](http://blogs.msdn.com/johnwpowell/archive/2008/09/20/how-to-create-a-reusable-wcf-service-host-for-windows-services-and-self-hosting.aspx)'s one).

The only other way I could think of to do it would be to expose your own custom metadata endpoint built from WsdlExporter (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733782.aspx))

Good luck!

Comment: I have built a custom wsdl exporter. Its a bit hackish at the moment, but it basically works.

Answer (score 0):

Another option I am currently researching is a third party soap client for PHP called [WSF-PHP](http://wso2.org/projects/wsf/php).